# is there a hosting for jqueryui minified libarary

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a minified version of jQueryUI  hosted in the script hosting websites?

I want to use jQueryUI in my website, its about 425KB and as the internet speed is an issue for my users I want to use a minified version of it. the uncompressed version is hosted on jquery.com:

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js

but I need the minified version. and I don't want to host it in my own website. because I compressed it and it is still about 280KB.

Comment: Took me about 30 seconds to find [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui).  I can guarantee it took you longer to type this question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - 30 seconds? You're losing your touch.

Comment: @j08691: I included the time it took me to read the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - was starting to wonder if you were on dial-up.

Comment: sorry but I live in Iran and the link you gave me is not working for me: I see this: 403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL /speed/libraries/devguide from this server. (Client IP address: x.x.x.x)

We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country. That’s all we know.

Comment: The minified version in the Google Hosted Libraries is still 228K in size.  If you need it smaller than that, go to http://jqueryui.com/download/, build a custom version of the library, and minify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the hosted libraries that google has?
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

here is the current version of JqueryUI:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 3):

It's on google's hosted libraries: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui